# Compare 2 dates in string format in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net

I try to compare these 2 dates in string format but it couldnt work out 
{

```
       SqlCommand cmd =new SqlCommand($"SELECT Last_Login_Date FROM [dbo].[Member] WHERE EmailAddress='{emailAddress}');") ;
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string lld = reader["Last_Login_Date"].ToString();
        string currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();if (DateTime.Parse(lld,currentDate))
```

}

Comment: Has this anything to do with the php tag?

Comment: what did you mean `compare these 2 dates in string format` ? what's wrong with converting them into `DateTime` and compare them ?

Comment: No. I'm using c# asp.net. I retrieve from sql server to get the last_login_date to compare to current_date. Both of the date are in string format so I don't know how to do the comparison

Comment: i tried to use DateTime.Compare(currentdate,last_login_date) and this error pops out
(cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.DateTime')

Answer (score 1):

Make sure data type of Last_Login_Date is datetime or date.

I'll use `GetDateTime` to get value.

SQL Server
[SqlDataReader.GetDateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime?view=netframework-4.8)

MySQL [MySqlDataReader.GetDateTime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataReader_GetDateTime.htm)

like this `reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("ColumnName"));`

So you will change your `string lld` to `DateTime lld`

ex:`DateTime lld = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("ColumnName"));`

Then compare two variables `DateTime.Compare(currentDate,lld)`.

Hope this help !

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use datefunctions on string. Read the date from datareader and add your comparision logic.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand($"SELECT Last_Login_Date FROM [dbo].[Member] WHERE EmailAddress='{emailAddress}';"))
{
    DateTime lastlogindate;
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        lastlogindate = reader.GetDateTime("Last_Login_Date");
        //add your comparision logic here        
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Compare(lastlogindate, DateTime.Now)); //result -1    
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried your code and this error pop out
 ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.

Comment: @HowToGame, you need to set the connection to `SqlCommand`. I have changed the code to include connection